# Retrieve multiple rows from table2 based on single row from table1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables and I am using SQL Server.

table1 structure is

```
Campiagn_Id  Campiagn_Name 
1            test1
2            test2
3            test3
```

and table2 structure is

```
Campign_Id  EmalList
1           email_list_1
1           email_list_2
3           email_list_3
1           email_list_4
2           email_list_5
2           email_list_6
3           email_list_7
1           email_list_8
```

Now I want to fetch all the Campiagn_Id and Campiagn_Name from `table1` and also all the respective `EmalList` from `table2` in one query.

My Result will look like this

```
Campign_Id   Campiagn_Name    EmailList 
1            test1            email_list_1,email_list_2,email_list_4,email_list_8
2            test2            email_list_5,email_list_6
3            test3            email_list_3,email_list_7
```

Or any other suggested output will be fine

I think my question is pretty much clear to all of you.

Comment: Basic SQL questions are not on-topic for this site http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT 
    camp.Campiagn_Id, 
    camp.Campiagn_Name, 
    camp_list.Campign_Id, 
    camp_list.EmalList 
FROM 
    [table1] AS camp 
    LEFT JOIN [table2] AS camp_list ON (camp.Campiagn_Id = camp_list.Campiagn_Id);
```

This will show all campaigns with all emails lists for each campaign. It will show also campaign with no emails list.

You can add or remove fields in the select as you need.